# Understanding time series plot and ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a simple bar plot in R which groups dates and amounts grouped by month.

Although I have a basic understanding of R, I am struggling to understand why it's behaving the way it is.

So far, this is my progress:

[image: Basic R plot]

As you can see, I am using two simple variables: amount_net for the amounts and month_year_begindate for the time series. Here's an example of my data:

```
> head(df)
  amount_net month_year_begindate
1    3306.11           2017-10-01
2    5471.28           2018-07-01
3    4584.86           2018-07-01
4    5923.76           2018-07-01
5    3830.59           2018-07-01
6    4035.04           2018-07-01
```

Here's the code I used to create the graph:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(scales)

g <- ggplot(data = df)

g + geom_bar(aes(x = month_year_begindate , y = amount_net), stat="identity",
             colour = "dodgerblue3") +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", labels = date_format("%B de %Y"))  +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0, hjust = 1))
```

However, I fail to understand two basic things:

1. Why is R not colouring all data blue as asked? There are no missing or NA values in the data.
2. Why is R including two months which have no data ("julio de 2017" and "septiembre de 2019")? Also, if I use `limits = as.Date(c('2019-01-01', '2019-05-01'))` I see the same behaviour (values at beginning and end being shown as empty).

Anyone that can help me understand and solve this?

Comment: 1) It's `fill = "dodgerblue3"` not `colour = <value>`, this is for the *border only*. 2) Are you sure that `amount_net` is numeric and not of class `"factor"`? Check with the output of `str(df)`.

Comment: Hi @RuiBarradas! Thanks for your observation, you are absolutely right about fill. As per `amount_net` it is stored as numeric

Comment: Your data seems problematic, and apparently need some additional summarizing: you have in your sample data 5 different values for "2018-07-01". How do you expect to plot them as a bar? Shouldn you have **only one** "2019-07-01" and the [mean / sum / median / whatever] for the `amount_net` column?

Comment: Hi @PavoDive, thank you for your comment. I have more than 3,000 individual observations in my data, each has a different date but I have summarized it as having the same day (preserving year and month) for plotting purposes. I could summarize it further so as to extract the sum of each month in a different dataframe, but first I wanted to understand why the two empty months are being plotted.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the problem can be caused because of an excessive `width` of the bars. See this example with your toy data (notice that I summarized it by date):

```
library(data.table)

dt[, month_year_begindate := lubridate::ymd(month_year_begindate)]

ggplot(dt[, .(amount_net = sum(amount_net)), by = month_year_begindate]) + 
     geom_bar(aes(x = month_year_begindate , y = amount_net), 
              stat="identity",
              fill = "dodgerblue3", 
              width = 5) +
     scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", labels = date_format("%B de %Y"))  +
     theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0, hjust = 1))
```

[image]